# Jolt Transformation issues for breaking out values into key and value

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to use Jolt to transform my json to break up the content into key / value to perform a reverse transform to a legacy system. Here is my sample input:

```json
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

My desired out put is:

```json
{
  "keyValuePair": [
    {
      "key": "key1",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    {
      "key": "key2",
      "value": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on how I can modify the spec for the desired result?

Note: I need this in a general case, the keys and values could be any random values so hard coding the pairing is not an option.

I have tried several different specs, the one that is the closest is this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "*": {
          "$0":  "keyValuePair[].key",
          "@(0)": "keyValuePair[].value"
        }
      }
  }
]
```

However this is the output:

```json
{
  "keyValuePair": [
    {
      "key": "key1"
    },
    {
      "value": "value1"
    },
    {
      "key": "key2"
    },
    {
      "value": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "keyValuePair[#2].key", 
        "@": "keyValuePair[#2].value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- **[ ]** generates arraywise results
- **#2** nested within **[ ]** is used to reach the uppermost asterisk symbol which represents the indexes to loop through each attribute as counting up the tree by traversing `:` as **1**st,
  traversing `{` **2**nd level.  eg. : start counting from ***1*** for the RHS symbol **[# ]** unlike to the RHS  **[& ]**, for which start counting the levels with ***0***. This missing part separates the objects by each attribute. eg. it generates two of them instead of four.
- **$** represents keys, and **@** represents values respectively

*** RHS : Right Hand Side

the **demo** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]